# How to get or install gksu for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, snap

Just two days ago I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 22.04, and noticed that `gksu` isn't available for it.
`sudo apt-get install -y gksu`

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done Package gksu is not available, but is
> referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
> missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate

Not even `snap` has it.
`snap install gksu`

> error: snap "gksu" not found

How to install and use `gksu`? Has it been replaced by some other program?

**Update:** I just found that `gksu` [is deprecated](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/), so it'd help to have some example commands that show how older `gksu` commands can be replaced with new ones. I'm sure this will help everyone who reaches this page searching for what happened to `gksu`.

Comment: Thanks. So the solution is to use `alias gksu='pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY'`